# Linking Errors when using static function

Tags: c++, static

I am new to c++ and am attempting make a program with opengl for simulating satellite orbits. I currently have three files, main.cpp, window.h, and window.cpp. I can create a window, but seeing as my application may need more than one window open at a time I wanted to implement a window manager of sorts. Upon trying to do so I have encountered a linking error. The code below compiles and runs as intended.

main.cpp

```
    #include "window.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

    int main() {
        Window window("Space Sim", 800, 600);

        //Sets the background color of the window
        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.8f, 1.0f);
        std::cout << glGetString(GL_VERSION) << std::endl;

        while (!window.closed()) {
            window.clear();

            glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
            glVertex2f(-0.5f, 0.5f);
            glVertex2f(0.0f, 0.5f);
            glVertex2f(0.5f, -0.5f);
            glEnd();

            window.update();
        }

        glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}
```

window.h

```
#pragma once
#include <GLFW\glfw3.h>

class Window {
    private:
        const char *title;
        int width, height;
        GLFWwindow *window;
        bool init();

    public:
        Window(const char *title, int width, int height);
        ~Window();
        void clear() const;
        bool closed() const;
        void update();
        void setSize(int width, int height);

        inline bool isWindow(GLFWwindow* window) { return this->window == window; }
        inline int getWidth()const { return width; }
        inline int getHeight() const { return height; }
};
```

window.cpp

```
#include <GLFW\glfw3.h>
#include "window.h"
#include <iostream>

Window::Window(const char *title, int width, int height) {
    this->title = title;
    setSize(width, height);
    if (!init()) {
        glfwTerminate();
    }
}

Window::~Window() {
    //This may be incorrect
    window = NULL;
}

void Window::update() {
    glfwPollEvents();
    glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &width, &height);
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
}

void Window::clear() const {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
}

bool Window::closed() const {
    return glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == 1;
}

bool Window::init() {
    if (!glfwInit()) {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLFW" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, title, NULL, NULL);
    if (!window) {
        glfwTerminate();
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize window" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    return true;
}

void Window::setSize(int width, int height) {
    this->width = width;
    this->height = height;
}
```

However, when an empty static function is added to window as framebuffer_size_callback the linker errors show up on building.

window.h

```
#pragma once
#include <GLFW\glfw3.h>    

class Window {
        private:
            const char *title;
            int width, height;
            GLFWwindow *window;
            bool init();

        public:
            Window(const char *title, int width, int height);
            ~Window();
            void clear() const;
            bool closed() const;
            void update();
            void setSize(int width, int height);
            static void framebuffer_size_callback();

            inline bool isWindow(GLFWwindow* window) { return this->window == window; }
            inline int getWidth()const { return width; }
            inline int getHeight() const { return height; }
    };
```

window.cpp with static method

```
#include <GLFW\glfw3.h>
#include "window.h"
#include <iostream>

Window::Window(const char *title, int width, int height) {
    this->title = title;
    setSize(width, height);
    if (!init()) {
        glfwTerminate();
    }
}

Window::~Window() {
    //This may be incorrect
    window = NULL;
}

void Window::update() {
    glfwPollEvents();
    glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &width, &height);
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
}

void Window::clear() const {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
}

bool Window::closed() const {
    return glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == 1;
}

bool Window::init() {
    if (!glfwInit()) {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLFW" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, title, NULL, NULL);
    if (!window) {
        glfwTerminate();
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize window" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    return true;
}

void Window::setSize(int width, int height) {
    this->width = width;
    this->height = height;
}

void Window::framebuffer_size_callback() {

}
```

and the error is:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall
>   Window::Window(char const *,int,int)" (??0Window@@QAE@PBDHH@Z)
>   referenced in function
>   _main SpaceSim    C:\Users\Cameron\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\SpaceSim\SpaceSim\main.obj   1    Error  LNK2019 unresolved
>   external symbol "public: __thiscall Window::~Window(void)"
>   (??1Window@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function
>   _main SpaceSim    C:\Users\Cameron\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\SpaceSim\SpaceSim\main.obj   1    Error  LNK2019 unresolved
>   external symbol "public: void __thiscall Window::clear(void)const "
>   (?clear@Window@@QBEXXZ) referenced in function
>   _main SpaceSim    C:\Users\Cameron\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\SpaceSim\SpaceSim\main.obj   1    Error  LNK2019 unresolved
>   external symbol "public: bool __thiscall Window::closed(void)const "
>   (?closed@Window@@QBE_NXZ) referenced in function
>   _main SpaceSim    C:\Users\Cameron\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\SpaceSim\SpaceSim\main.obj   1    Error  LNK2019 unresolved
>   external symbol "public: void __thiscall Window::update(void)"
>   (?update@Window@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function
>   _main SpaceSim    C:\Users\Cameron\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\SpaceSim\SpaceSim\main.obj   1    Error  LNK1120 5 unresolved
>   externals SpaceSim    C:\Users\Cameron\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\SpaceSim\Debug\SpaceSim.exe 1

Inside my visual studio project I have the dll and include files for glfw, but I don't understand why i get a linker error when the static function seems correct and doesn't do anything. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is definitely not due to the static method. You are not linking with your "window.cpp" for some reason. Check your build process.

Comment: I am not very familiar with visual studio. How do you I go about doing that and is there anything I should be looking for in particular?